# mysql create table with decimal not null

Tags: mysql

This blows up at the amount decimal(3,2) not null, line

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nutrition (
    foodID INT NOT NULL,
    measurmentID NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL,
    calories INT NOT NULL,
    carbs DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL,
    fat DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL,
    protein DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL,
    sodium DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL,
    fiber DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: Actually, it fails here: `measurmentID NOT NULL,`, because you haven't specified a field type.

Comment: Palm to forehead, arggg. Thanks, sorry for wasting everyones time

Answer (score 1):

`measurementID NOT NULL` has no type definition.